# Enhanced LWR - Not able to Publish modifications - Error ID: 1385547353-13911 (413072119)

Tags: community, experience-cloud, digital-experience, lwr, salesforce-cms

I've recently created a B2B enhanced LWR experience Cloud.
When, you create a B2B LWR site, a CMS workspace is automatically created.
The CMS workspace default language is set as Polish and the site available languages are French and English.

I've created a new French default language CMS Workspace, and attached it to the Site thanks to the Workspace Channels.
After doing that, i wasn't able to publish any modification i've made from the Experience Builder.

**Here is the error we faced** :

```
has been notified of the problem. 
If you believe you have additional information that may be of help in reproducing or correcting the error, please contact Salesforce Support. 
Please indicate the URL of the page you were requesting, any error id shown on this page as well as any other related information. We apologize for the inconvenience.

Thank you again for your patience and assistance. And thanks for using salesforce.com!
Error ID: 1385547353-13911 (413072119)
```

[image]

---

**Notes** :

- CMS workspace cannot be deleted
- CMS workspace cannot be unlinked to Experience Site

---

**Questions**

- Do you have an idea for solving this problem?
- Do you have any idea what to look for in the Salesforce configuration or logs?

Comment: Just like with your previous question, this is a GACK and there's not much of anything that we can do with that error id (since >= 99% of us here are customers/users of Salesforce, and not Salesforce employees). If you aren't finding anything when you search for the number in the parenthesis, then you need to go through Salesforce's official customer support to get help with this.